# Generate multiple profile charts from multiple lines on multiple DEM

Tags: dem, cad, profile, cross-section

I'm trying to figure out how to generate automatically (need to be repeated 2k times) a profile cut of 2 DEMs, every 10 meters, with distance from start as a title and customizable colors/scales as an output. In short, Im trying to make something like this :

[image: A profile cut of 2 DEMs]

Honestly, I'm trying to get Civil3D out of my workflow. Would love a ArcGIS solution but doubt it. QGIS maybe? FME?

I know all the process to get the lines at every 10 meters following my centerline. I just don't know where to go from there to get a result as above.

Comment: You'll need to invest in Python. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181390/accessing-graph-properties-in-arcpy