# Adjusting axes limits of graph in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graph, arcgis-10.7

Is there a way to adjust the axis limits in the [built-in graph tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/graphs/creating-scatter-plot-graphs.htm) in ArcMap?

I have looked all over and cannot find it. It would be easier to just adjust the axes than to save a new shapefile with the extra points removed.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181390/accessing-graph-properties-in-arcpy

Comment: thanks @FelixIP. Is there a way to create and embed a plot from matplotlib while working in the Python window in ArcMap? I have searched but didn't find anything on getting started with matplotlib in ArcMap

Comment: Where do you want it? There's picture element in layout view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope example below will kick-start you using matplotlib module with ArcGIS.

Table:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
inFc = r'C:\SCRATCH\SCRATCH.gdb\points'
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(inFc, ("D_ALONG","Z"))
line,=plt.plot(tbl["D_ALONG"],tbl["Z"])
plt.title("Rangitoto Caldera")
plt.savefig('F:/AERIALS/PNGs/Example.png')
```

Output:

[image]