# Changing the legend element anchor point using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, legend, anchor-point

Is it possible to changed the legend element anchor point using ArcPy?

This is the default anchor point:

[image]

and i want this anchor point location:

[image]

I know how to changed the legend element position x,y. But if the anchor point isn't in the right place, then i will get unwanted result.

Comment: If you are desperate though, you may wish to have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anchor point of a [legend element](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/legendelement-class.htm#P_GUID-BA2C3D94-8CA7-42FC-9E85-A4E7EAD78F83) is not available as a property to ArcPy.  Consequently, you will need to author them into a map.

There is an ArcGIS Idea to be able to [Get and set layout element anchor points in ArcPy](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/3634) that you may want to add your vote to:

> You can access the XY positions of the elements, but these are in
>   relation to their anchor point which could be different for each
>   element. This would be very helpful for map automation scripts, as I
>   currently have to make separate versions of my scripts for MXDs that
>   have slightly different layout elements or page sizes.