# Zoom to the whole page using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layouts, zoom

I work with several MXD files. When opening those MXD files, i want to see the whole layout view, as this button function:
[image].

Is there a way, using arcpy, zooming to the whole page in the layout view, so in the next time i will open those MXD files, the default will be the layout view, zooming to the whole page?

I started to write this code, but i don't know how to continue with it:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
     print mxdname
     mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
     df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0] 
     mxd.activeView='PAGE_LAYOUT' 
     print 'PAGE_LAYOUT'
     mxd.save()
del  mxd
```

This code don't zooming to the whole page, but change from data view to layout view, and that isn't my complete goal.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not exposed via arcpy. You will need either to write a [.NET/Java add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/) or [call ArcObjects from Python using comtypes.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python)