# Zoom to percent using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layouts

How can I zoom to 55% using arcpy in the layout view, instead of doing it manually with "Zoom to percent" button? I have 55 maps and I prefer doing it automatically with arcpy code.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is not exposed via arcpy. You will need either to write a [.NET/Java add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/) or [call ArcObjects from Python using comtypes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python).