# Importing Functionality from Python Addin into script

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible without using Arcobjects, but what I want to do is use a piece of a prebuilt addin created by ESRI and then add it into my own Arcpy script. The specific addin is the Curves and Lines addin and the Curvinator functionality is what I am after. I know it is possible to call a script from within another script but I can't figure out how to call the toolbar button from within a script or whether it is even possible. The addin is available at http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b59665cb906a435da3f8c45332d7cfdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Curves and Lines add-in is **not** a *python* add-in.  It is probably a .Net ArcObjects add-in.

I determined this by downloading the add-in and extracting the files using an unzip application.  Inside I only found `.dll` and related files, no python files.  A Python add-in would include the `.py` files.

If it were a Python add-in it would be possible to extract the `.py` file from the add-in and reference that from your script.

It is possible to call ArcObjects from `arcpy`, and you may be able to use that to access your add-in tools.

See [Accessing ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python)