# Is there a way to control the legends of cartographic representations with Python?

Tags: arcpy, cartography, line, legend, representation

I have a ArcGIS feature class with 3 cartographic representations.  Two of them represent the features with line offsets.  These representations are determined based on multiple fields.  One field determines the color of the line, the other field determines the offset.  In the legend this means that each color is repeated once for each offset.  This can be controlled using Layer Properties>Symbology>Legend Options to make it so that each line color is only shown once in the legend.  Is there a way to control this setting with Python?

Comment: Can you please describe the workflow you are trying to achieve with Python?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to access this using `arcpy`. Currently, your only option is to search for custom tools that other users might have built or develop your own using [ArcObjects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Working_with_layers_and_renderers/000100000468000000/).

Comment: In the Accessing ArcObjects from Python [question] (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python)  on SO there are some links for snippets.py for convenient loading ArcObjects libraries and work with them. This helped me create .mxd file and tune TOC according to style file in python.