# Ungroup ArcMap Graphic Elements in Layout using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, layouts, graphics, element

I want to alter text elements in a layout. This text elements were grouped. Grouped elements behave like *GraphicElement* and it is possible to query the property *isGroup*. I can not alter these text elements before ungrouping.

[image]

**Is it possible to ungroup these GraphicElements using arcpy?**

**EDIT:**

My reasoning for this question is false. As Alex Tereshenkov points out: **you can alter grouped text elements.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using python script to call arcobject LayoutTools_Ungroup command using comtypes, see:

[Accessing ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python)

and

[ArcMap Commands](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/858a508c-b771-467c-81e6-c6aa72d88f9c.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the code on 10.3.1 and 10.5. You don't need to ungroup the graphic element in order to change the text of the group's items.

In other words, you should be able to alter the properties (eg `text`) of a `TEXT_ELEMENT` even if it is grouped and is a part of a `GRAPHIC_ELEMENT`.

The original image:

[image]

```
>>> import arcpy.mapping as mp
>>> 
>>> mxd = mp.MapDocument('current')
>>> elems = mp.ListLayoutElements(mxd)
>>> t2 = elems[1]
>>> t2.type
u'TEXT_ELEMENT'
>>> t2.text
u'Text2'
>>> t2.text = 'Changed text 1'
>>> t2.text
'Changed text 1'
```

The text elements remain grouped after the changes are performed.

[image]

You can also move the items around:

```
>>> t1.elementPositionY
11.809199999999691
>>> t1.elementPositionY += 2
```

[image]

Comment: I got stuck in theory, before trying it.

Comment: @EikeMike, no worries. Glad it worked out well for you.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a way to do this from ArcPy then I would expect to see `ungroup` amongst the [methods on the GraphicElement class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/graphicelement-class.htm#M2_GUID-5CDC9B5D-E6E6-4650-A06C-6ECEDABCF7F5).

As you can see from its documentation there is not one.

Consequently, you may want to consider looking for or submitting an ArcGIS Idea.

There is no `ungroup` method for the [GraphicElement class for ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/graphicelement-class.htm) either.