# Using Access Hyperlink Field Type in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf, ms-access, hyperlink

I've been searching for an answer to my particular issue, but haven't turned up any answers after a couple days of searching. I am using Access 2013 and ArcInfo 10.X

My issue is:

I have an Access 2013 database containing land transaction records in a hyperlink field that is concatenated from several different fields to generate a file path. The hyperlink field displays text (i.e., a person's name) which hyperlinks to the appropriate folder. I have underlying information organized in the database where personal information broken up into several fields that auto-generates the file path to a folder that will contain PDFs.

Everything functions well in Access. However, when I establish the OLE DB connection in ArcCatalog, the field type is not recognized as a hyperlink field and in ArcMap (as expected) and is imported as a string.

My question is:

**In ArcMap, can you import Access functionality, such as the hyperlink field generated from concatenated fields represented by text, and not the actual file path?**

I have tried a couple workarounds, such as inputting the base URL in the MXD properties and designating a field to specify the exact folder. This works just fine, but I will eventually have several additional paths per parcel that I'll need to add for historical land transaction data. Ideally, a given tract of land will have several hyperlinked PDF's with the hyperlinks represented by the concatenated field (auto-generated from the Access form).

I'm under the impression this could probably be solved through a python script, but am at a loss of how to do it.

Comment: If you wish to ask the same question about QGIS or ArcGIS Pro, then just do that in a separate question and describe what you have tried and where you are stuck with those products.

Comment: The hyperlink is a property of the *layer* and not the *feature class*, read http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000004000000 there is no field type Hyperlink, only String. It is not a property that can be modified with python unless you use ArcObjects https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python/110#110, see snippet http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000024000000 on how to add a hyperlink with ArcObjects.