# Turning off ArcMap Editor via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing, python-addin

I have a problem with turning on or off ArcMap editor, using arcpy.

When I try to turn on editor on arcpy I use this code on ArcMap Python window

```
workspace = r'C:\tests\test.mdb'        
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing()
edit.startOperation()
```

But it doesn't activate editor. When I do this process with using Editor - Start Editing on Arcmap, I try to test it with this code :

```
workspace = r'C:\tests\test.mdb'
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
xa = edit.isEditing()
print xa
```

It returns False, Although editing is on.

I need to deactivate editor in my Python add-in script. So, i have to use arcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with arcpy.da.Editor. Actually, the only way to control edit session is to use ArcObjects ([IEditor Interface](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm?lg=en#IEditor.htm)). It is possible to do with Python using Comtypes ([Accessing Arcobjects From Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python))