# Python script to turn off a checkbox in all layers in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, layers, loop, update

I need to remove the check for all the layers on a map that has the "UT Simbology" check. I am not really sure If I could use update layer because this is an extension developed by a GIS company for utilities and I am not really sure how to do that because it is not an Esri command.

Which Python command could I use for that?

I need to save all the layers simbology then, but if I have the UT simbology checked, it does not work on ArcGIS Pro.
[image]

Comment: You won't be able to use simple `arcpy` commands if this is a custom extension. You **might** be able to use `comtypes`, but that's only a guess. I'm not sure if you can access custom extensions with them. You can read more here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python

Comment: I would go back to the source company and ask them to develop that capability into their extension. They could expose that as a button on a toolbar.